Finding the point on $y^2=4x$ whose tangent is parallel to $y=x+1$. Taking square roots leads to incorrect answers.
I don't understand how using square root seems to change the function.
The question - Find the point on $y^2=4x$ whose tangent is parallel to $y=x+1$.
The Issue
Now if you write this as ${y=\sqrt{4x}}$ and then differentiate you get ${y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$. And since $y'$ should be parallel to the given line, its slope should be $1$ and therefore, x=1. But, substituting x=1, you get both the points ${(1,2)}$ and $(1,-2)$. But only $(1,2)$ has slope as 1.
And so, the correct method seems to be not using square-roots but instead differentiating as an implicit function to get $2y.y'=4$. But I don't understand why the first method does not work.
When I asked a few people, I generally got the answer that roots give 'mirror terms' and to, just in general, stay away from using roots. Square roots just seem messy to me overall. Could someone please explain the square root function and why it seems to change the equation.
NOTE: I've seen a few questions on the principal solution of square roots in here, but none seem to discuss anything similar to the question I got stuck on (and the weird "mirror solutions") so I think this warrants a separate question.

It might be helpful to plot $y^2=4x$. Furthermore, you can ask yourself, what heppens when $y$ is positive, or if it is negative?

When we say "the square root" we mean the principal root, i.e., the positive root. The square root function only returns this thing (otherwise it isn't a function!).

I understand that the square root function returns only the possible value. My question is more, why does writing $y^2=4x$ as $y=\sqrt{4x}$ yield different results on differentiation

$\sqrt{2}$ is a positive number. The equation $x^2=2$ has two solutions, $\sqrt{2}$ and -$\sqrt{2}$. You just have to be clear in your own mind what you are doing.

"But, substituting x=1, you get both the points (1,2)
and (1,−2)" How so? If you substitute $x=1$ into $y=\sqrt{4x}$, you get $y=2$. Are you getting the derivative from one equation, and plugging $x$ into a different one (namely, $y^2=4x$)?

@Acccumulation hmm true. I missed that as well. My mistake was thinking that the two equations were completely equivalent, and using them interchangeably.

When solving $y^2 = 4x$, the solution $y=\pm 2\sqrt{x}$ is a shorthand for a set of solutions which contains two points:
$$ y \in \{2\sqrt{x}, -2\sqrt{x}\}.$$
Algebraically, the usual approach is to find these solutions by factoring a polynomial and then using the Zero Factor Theorem to finish the problem:
$$ y^2 = 4x \iff 0 = y^2 - 4x = (y-2\sqrt{x})(y+2\sqrt{x}). $$
Assuming that this problem is over the real numbers, $x$ must be assumed to be nonnegative, and $\sqrt{x}$ is the principal square root.  Thus there are two solutions.  The first is obtained by supposing that $y-2\sqrt{x} = 0$, and the other is obtained by supposing that $y+2\sqrt{x} = 0$.
The existence two general families of solutions (as $x$ varies) can also be seen from the graph:

For any particular positive value of $x$, there will be two different values of $y$ such that the point $(x,y)$ is on that blue curve.  (And there is only one corresponding value of $y$ when $x=0$, and no corresponding $y$-values otherwise.)
The question then asks for a point on this blue curve such that the tangent line at that point is parallel to the line $y=x+1$ (that is, the goal is to find a point on this curve such that $y'=1$).  Off the top of my head, there are two productive approaches here:

This curve actually consists of two different branches.  The upper branch is the graph of $y=2\sqrt{x}$, while the lower branch is the graph of $y=-2\sqrt{x}$.  First, try to find a point on the upper branch which has the desired property:
$$ y' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 1 \implies x = 1.$$
If $x=1$, then $y=2$, so $(1,2)$ is a point on the upper branch with the desired property.  Next, try to solve the problem on the lower branch:
$$ y' = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 1, $$
which has no real solutions.  So there are no points on the lower branch with the desired property.
Therefore the only point on the curve $y^2 = 4x$ at which the tangent line is parallel to $y = x+1$ is $(1,2)$.

An alternative approach is to use implicit differentiation.  Since $y$ is a function of $x$, both sides of the equation can be differentiated to give
$$ y^2 = 4x \implies 2 y y' = 4 \implies y' = \frac{2}{y}. $$
The goal is to find a point $(x,y)$ where $y'=1$, so substitute that in and solve for $y$:
$$ 1 = y' = \frac{2}{y} \implies y = 2. $$
When $y=2$, $x=1$, giving the point $(1,2)$ as the only point on $y^2 = 4x$ where $y'=1$.


